# Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(".") has different result on windows and linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, resources

I have a simple Java class:

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(Thread
              .currentThread()
              .getContextClassLoader()
              .getResource("."));
    }
}
```

Running the above class on windows I got:

```
file:/T:/java/
```

While running it on Linux I got a different stuff:

```
jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar!/
```

This problem caused my program failed on Linux as it cannot find the files I specified. Any idea on how to workaround it?

Comment: what are you expecting `"."` to return?

Comment: The current folder when starting the java program. Actually this doesn't matter, what I want is use `Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader().getResource("app.conf")` to get the `app.conf` file. It works on windows, but not on Linux.

Comment: Got to love the documentation on that method "The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource." So name is String that may or may not have '/' characters in it.

Comment: @green The current directory? Why not just use `File`. Resource is about loading "files" which are part of the program. In production deployments, the current working directory is unlikely to be on the classpath (perhaps).

Comment: as I said the current working directory is just to testing the API's behavior on the 2 envs, it doesn't matter. I want use the program to load a configuration file, which might exists in the current directory or in the lib's jar file root

Comment: Classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit your question with the contents of your last comment, as that appears to be your *actual* goal.

Answer (score 2):

The program's current directory may or may not be in the classpath, depending on how the program is executed.  if you need to get something which may be in a jar file or may be in the current dir, then you should use two separate checks:

1. first check the classpath
2. if not found then check the current directory (you can get the current working directory using `new File("")`).

Comment: Thx, how can i get the running program's class path root directory?

Comment: For example, suppose the class path root is `./target/test-classes`, and I want to get a folder `./target/test-classes/resources` directory, how can I get it from the java app?

Comment: @green - why are you trying to get the directory of the root classpath?  the program may be running from a jar which doesn't _have_ a root directory.

Comment: That is the case I am running the unit test cases where the program is not start from the jar file